# Issues on using Axios to send HTTP request from a localhost Express API to another

Tags: node.js, express, axios, localhost

I have a Express API sitting on 127.0.0.1:8001
and the endpoint code is like

```
    app.get('/api/register-logging', async (req, res)=> {
       try {
            await axios.get('127.0.0.1:5000/register', {
               name:"shawn"
           }).then( response => {
               console.log(response.data);
               res.json(response.data);
           })
       }catch (e){
           console.log(e);
       }
    });
```

I have another flask service sitting on 127.0.0.1:5000 has an /register endpoint for the request abobe, I have installed the CORS in my express but I am still getting errors in the following

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 5000
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '5000',
  config: {
    url: 'localhost:5000/register',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.0'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    name: 'amber',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: false,
      closed: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      protocol: 'http:',
      path: '/register',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: '5000',
      port: null,
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/register'
    },
    _ended: true,
    _ending: true,
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'GET /register HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.0\r\n' +
        'Host: 5000\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/register',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: '5000',
      protocol: 'http:',
      _redirectable: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'http://5000/register',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Judging from  _currentUrl: 'http://5000/register', looks like the server cannot intepret the URI, I have used POSTMAN to test the /register endpoint which is workable,I can not make it work inside the API. I have enabled the 127.0.0.1 localhost configuration in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc  Host File. Did not solve the issue, PLease Help. THank you very much!!

Comment: try using `http://127.0.0.1:5000/register`

Comment: @AnujPancholi YES! IT WORKS, thanks so much sir!! I've stuck on this for a whole night!